# loop through rows and copy a range of values of that row to an array

Tags: arrays, vba, copy, row, range

My problem while using VBA is trying to create a loop that copies a range of cells from a range of rows.

The loop has to copy a range of cells from the same row and worksheet to an array.
This worked for one row:

```
CheckArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("DTMs").Range("B2:F2"))
```

What I would like to create is a loop that does this for the row "i"

After creating an array with the info from the range of cells, I compare it with another array. After comparing I jump a row down and repeat the creation of the array. Like so:

For i = 1 to ID_cnt    ------->'ID_cnt is the maximal range of the rows I would like to loop trough

CheckArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("sheet12").Range("B(i):F(i)"))

Next

This doesn't work. I have no idea how to write the loop so that the array will be created with the info contained in the range of cells (B to F) from row "i" and how to repeat this in the loop.

Sequence:

1) Row ( i ): copy (B to F) and fill in the array

2) Check the array's content and compare to another array

3) Jump to row (i + 1): repeat process.

The maximal amount of jumps is automatically set by a ID_cnt variable that counts the amount of rows containing information.

Please help me and thanks in advance (& sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the range of cells like the following:

```
For i = 1 to ID_cnt 

    CheckArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("sheet12").Range("B" & i & ":F" & i))

Next
```

You might also do something which is more clean like:

```
dim myRngStr as string
myRngStr = "B" & i & ":F" & i
    CheckArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("sheet12").Range(myRngStr))
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, my comparing quarry works like a charm now! Cudos to you Sir!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CheckArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("sheet12").Range("B" & i & ":F" & i))
```

Comment: Thank you for this short version, you both made my program work now!